# Running python from command line gives import error

Tags: python, command-line

I want to run my python program from command line but it gives me below error

```
ImportError: No module named 'main'
```

My folder structure is as below

```
Project

|-----main

         |-----__init__.py

         |-----S3Operations.py 

         |-----BusinessOperations.py
```

My init.py code is as below

```
import sys
from S3Operations import Models
sys.path.append("D:/code/Project/main")
if __name__ == '__main__':
    s3=Models()
    s3.test()
```

And my S3Operations.py code is

```
import os.path
from main import BusinessService

class ModelsMlS3(object):

       def test(self):
         print("Testing success")
```

When I run the program using command line i get the below error

```
$ python __init__.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from S3Operations import ModelsMlS3
  File "D:\code\Project\main\S3Operations.py", line 11, in <module>
    from main import BusinessService
ImportError: No module named 'main'
```

Can any one please suggest a solution for the same.

Comment: Just try `import BusinessService` (i.e. without *import main*) and it should work

Comment: This solved my problem.Can you please write it as answer so i can mark it as solved

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to do:

```
import BusinessService  # instead of `from main import BusinessService`
```

as in your project, there is no `__init__.py` file present in `Project` directory (which holds `main.py`).

For importing it like:

```
from main import BusinessService
```

you need to create `__init__.py` in the folder in order to make it as module.